# Emailing group set-up in Gmail is displaying the email not the contact name

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I am the new secretary for a association.  I spent a great deal of time entering contacts from the group including Name and email.  When I sent my first group email it displayed the email instead of the names I had so painstakingly entered in my group contact list.  Can I change the display settings?  I am much more familiar with Zimbra (which I use at work) and very clumsy with Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you added to the group only the simple email address (username@domain.com) instead of the full email address ("First Name" ) corresponding to each contact.

Instead of adding the simple email addresses to a group, from [Create contact groups - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30970?hl=en) , ...

> To add contacts to a contact group:
>
> 1. Select the contacts in the Contacts list.
> 2. Click the **Groups** button [image: Groups button].
> 3. Select the group you'd like to add the contact to, or select **Create new** to create a new group.
> 4. If you have multiple addresses saved for a contact, you can choose which address should belong to the contact group by opening the
>      contact and clicking the small arrow next to the group you'd like to
>      modify.